# Generic PATH to CUDA header files in Windows and macOS

Tags: windows, macos, makefile, cuda, include-path

I'm writing a Makefile for a multi-platform project involving CUDA, where I need to make the path to CUDA header-files available. For Linux, I can safely assume that the CUDA header-files, if installed, would be residing in /usr/local/cuda/include. Unlike Linux, the paths for macOS (/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/include) and Windows (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include) are dependent on the version of the CUDA SDK. (These PATHS are partial guesses from reading CUDA documentation and TensorFlow's Makefile as I don't use these OSes)

Please help me with generic paths to the CUDA header files in the case of Windows and macOS.

Comment: I don't believe you can safely assume anything, even for the linux case (where the NVIDIA installer allows you to choose where to install all the toolkit files). You would be much better served by just designing the Makefile so that the user either edits it or passes the PATH as part of the build command, and clearly document how it is intended to be used

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable has zero bearing on the location of an SDK's include files. The CUDA installers set the `CUDA_PATH` variable, though, and that's the one you should be using.

Comment: @talonmies Yes you're right. I am giving the user the option to overide the default. But at the same time, I need to set the default path to something in case the user doesn't specify anything. In that sense, I meant that `/usr/local/cuda/` is a safe assumption because this is where CUDA is expected by default.

Comment: @IInspectable I wasn't talking about the `PATH` environment variable here.

Comment: If that was the intent, then using the term *"PATH"* was a pretty poor choice to convey that.

Comment: To complete @IInspectable answer, for Windows, you have a CUDA version string in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\@FirstVersionInstalled`